# DocumentBuilder.newDocument() is returning null

Tags: java, xml

Here is something I wouldn't have anticipated, and the documentation doesn't say whether this is even possible, but after calling DocumentBuilder's newDocument() method, it is returning null :

```
    // Initialize the DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder factories.
    try {
        m_docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        m_Log.error("m_docFactory is {}", m_docFactory);
        m_docBuilder = m_docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        m_Log.error("m_docBuilder is {}", m_docBuilder);
        m_doc = m_docBuilder.newDocument();
        m_Log.error("m_doc is {}", m_doc);
        m_xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        m_QCodeParameters = new QCodeParameters();
    }
    catch (DOMException e) {
        m_Log.error(e.toString());
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        m_Log.error(e.toString());
    }
```

The output I am getting is

```
m_docFactory is org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@f20d394c
m_docBuilder is org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@a7ce296c
m_doc is [#document: null]
```

Am I missing a jar?  Weird!

Comment: Is the `m_doc == null`, or is it just that the `toString()` method of m_doc returns null if there is no root element for instance?

Answer (score 3):

It's not returning `null`, otherwise it would've printed `m_doc is null`. But, the `toString` method of the `Document` that you just built is being called and is the following one in class `org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl`:

```
/** NON-DOM method for debugging convenience. */
public String toString() {
    return "["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]";
}
```

`getNodeValue()` is returning `null`

If you check the method in `NodeImpl`:

```
/**
 * Returns the node value.
 * @throws DOMException(DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR)
 */
public String getNodeValue()
    throws DOMException {
    return null;            // overridden in some subclasses
}
```

Try to access some attribute of `m_doc` and happy coding!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The object itself is not null, although the Document hasn't got any content. You should append *children* to it.